# Need to discuss a debugging scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I won't post any specific code for this question. My scenario is that I have a web app using node for the server side and some js files on the client side along with an index.html. The website has a form with text input and submit button. Now when I have setup the website it has to fetch data from an api as I enter some data and click submit.
But the issue is that I don't get any errors nor do I get any HTML rendered which I have setup in my js files. I have 304 status code on the chrome console but that's about the only information the console gives me. I don't know how to debug this kind of situation now. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
my index.js:

const URL = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?";
const username = "rohanasif1990";

const userInfo = document.getElementById("userInfo");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;

    if (city !== "") {
        getCountryInfo(URL, city, username)
            .then(function (info) {
                postData("/add", { lat: info.lat, lng: info.lng, country: info.country })
            }).then(function () {
                receiveData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("City not found");
            });
        userInfo.reset();
    }
    else {
        submitBtn.classList.add("invalid");
    }
})

const getCountryInfo = async (URL, city, username) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${URL}q=${city}&username=${username}`);
    try {
        const info = await res.json();
        return info['geonames'][0];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
};

const postData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            lat: data.lat,
            lng: data.lng,
            country: data.country
        })
    });
    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        return newData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const receiveData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch('/all');
    try {
        // Transform into JSON
        const allData = await request.json()
        // Write updated data to DOM elements
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = allData.lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = allData.lng;
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = allData.country;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        // appropriately handle the error
    }
}
```

the server.js file:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('client'));

app.get("/all", function sendData(req, res) {
    res.send(projectData);
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "../client/views" })
})

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    projectData['lng'] = req.body.lng;
    projectData['lat'] = req.body.lat;
    projectData['country'] = req.body.country;
    res.send(projectData);
})

// Setup Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Travel App listening on port 3000")
    console.log("Go to http://localhost:3000")
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Travel App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="application/css" href="../styles/styles.css">
    <script src="../index.js" type="application/json" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form">
            <form id="userInfo">
                <label for="city">Enter city: </label>
                <input type="text" id="city">
                <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="lat"></div>
            <div class="lng"></div>
            <div class="country"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The call to `userinfo.reset` appears to be made synchronously in the submit handler in the browser. Could  calling `userInfo.reset()` _before_ the promise handler  calls  `postData("/add", { lat: info.lat, lng: info.lng, country: info.country })` contribute to the problem?

Comment: let me check this

Comment: nope doesn't change anything.... same as before

Comment: Ok so when I submit some city name in the form the the url changes from "http://localhost:3000/" to "http://localhost:3000/?".. What does that mean?

Comment: The form has been submitted using a GET request, passing form data in the URL as a query component starting with `?`. The page has been reloaded from the server response to the GET.

Comment: What I can't reproduce is form submission - the `e.preventDefault()` is working correctly in cut-down test code.